# Why do I get "TypeError: input.match(...) is null"?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling

I have an input box and i want a specific alert according to what text you type in. I keep getting the error "TypeError: input.match(...) is null" when i type in something except "hello".

My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form5">
   <input type=text  size=51 name="input">
   <input onClick=auswert() type=button value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function auswert() {
var input = document.form5.input.value;

if (input.match(/hello/g).length == 1) alert("hello");
else alert("bye");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `input.match(/hello/g)` returns `null`, if there's no match. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is always useful.

Comment: or make a better logic if you don't want to read documentation. 
`if((input.match(/hello/g))&&(input.match(/hello/g).length == 1))`

Comment: Would be much better to assign the result of `.match()` to a variable than to perform the work of matching twice, since this can be CPU-intensive.

Comment: Or, untested, `if((input.match(/hello/g) || []).length == 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

From Mozilla Developer Network documentation for [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

"An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; null if there were no matches."

`input.match(/hello/g)` is returning null. Then you are invoking `length` on `null`. `null` does not have functions you can invoke on it.

I'd suggest you try:

```
if (input.match(/hello/g) == null) {
    // No Matches
    alert("bye");
} else {
    // Matches
    alert("hello");
}
```